# How to write all the available files in output file using listcat in JCL

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere

[image]

The above JCL will print the output in spool, but i need it to be written in the output file.

I want to print all the available files which starts with LCDT.TEST.FINAL.G* in the output file,so how to write the JCL to print the file name in the output file.

Comment: The above JCL seems to be a picture. You should put it in your question as text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*` you must write the SYSPRINT contents to a dataset like below:

```
//S010     EXEC PGM=IDCAMS    
//SYSPRINT DD DSN=ABC.XYZ.SYSPRINT,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//         SPACE=(CYL,(1,5),RLSE)
//SYSIN    DD *
  LISTCAT ENTRIES(LCDT.TEST.FINAL.*) ALL
/*
```

**EDIT:** Just noticed that this question is a possible duplicate of [How to list all the files in the output file using listcat in JCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671602/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-the-output-file-using-listcat-in-jcl/60673459#60673459)