# How to list all the files in the output file using listcat in JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl, websphere

[image]

The above JCL it only prints the file name in the spool,but we need to get all the files available with LCDT.TEST.FINAL.G* in one of the output file. So how can we achieve this by writing all the availble files with LCDT.TEST.FINAL.G* in the output file.

Comment: Please do not [post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3220910)

Comment: I don't know what this has to do with IBM Cloud. It does not matter where your datasets (they are not 'files') are located. If you want a list of them in a dataset then ditrect your SYSPRINT to a dataset instead of SYSOUT.

Comment: You are going to get all files into the spool or a dataset.  Your questions seems to indicate you want further filtering  LCDT.TEST.FINAL.G*   You can't do that with LISTCAT

Answer (score 4):

Your list of datasets is in the spool because that's where you route them by coding...

```
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
```

Route your SYSPRINT DD to a dataset instead of to the spool by coding...

```
//SYSPRINT DD  DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DSN=&SYSUID..LCDT.DATASET.LIST,
//             SPACE=(TRK,(10,10),RLSE)
```

...and IDCAMS should provide the appropriate RECFM and LRECL.